# Node.contains() devuelve error y no false si la referencia no existe

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy usando Chrome 73 y cuando intento ejecutar el siguiente código me devuelve un  Uncaught ReferenceError diciéndome que el elemento no está definido (en vez de devolverme false).

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log(document.body.contains(a));
}
```

Y Chrome me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined at window.onload (svcs.js:5)

Pero, si el elemento existe, la consola me devuelve true (lo que espero que me devuelva la función si el elemento existe).

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Podrías ampliar el código mostrando lo que significa a, para tener una mejor idea de la causa

Comment: @NickolasGarcia Ese es todo el código de JS, estaba haciendo pruebas. Básicamente este script se cargará en varias páginas en las cuales habrán elementos que no existirán en las demás, por ejemplo: el login tendrá un botón con id "doLogin" y el registro otro con id "doSignup", y este script, buscará si en la página que se ha cargado el script, existen estas ids, y sólo 1 coincidirá y le añadirá un addEventListener, y el otro devolverá false y no hará nada. Si quieres un código de ejemplo que debería funcionar, pero no lo hace, te lo puedo dejar también.

Comment: La cuestión es que la "a" lo interprea como varibale. Supongo que necesitarías cambiarlo a entre comillas: document.body.contains("a").

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que te salta una excepción debido a que el body del document aún no está creado. Personalmente, te recomendaría que probaras con el ready de JQuery, es similar al windows.onload, pero no exactamente igual.
Es decir en tu sección de javascript pon lo siguiente:

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    console.log(document.body.contains(a)); //CODE
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el resultado que deseas debes tener primeramente el nodo a, por medio de un código similar a este:

```
const a = document.getElementById('myid')
```

Y posteriormente verificar que se encuentre dentro del document con el código que tienes, lo cual es un poco redundante ya que para obtener el nodo ya hemos usado el document, por lo cual lo mas sencillo seria solamente usar la pieza de código que he colocado previamente y validarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
const a = document.querySelector('a')

if (a !== null) {
  // Existe
}
```